# Prevent highlighted text from deselecting when clicking an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a react application which allows for certain actions to be taken on highlighted text through a pop up.

**Confluence**

[image]

I'm using `react-text-selection-popover` which works very well. However, the pop up I have has an input field. The trouble I have is that if i were to click the input field (to enter some text), the highlight is deselected and the pop up disappears.

I tried options like `user-select: none` but it doesn't work.

[**Example Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-text-selection-popover-example-w6wbd)

Is there a way to highlight some text and enter some text in the pop-up div? And remove the highlight if i click anywhere else but the popup.

Comment: I wonder if confluence keeps the text highlighted or if it modified the HTML done how to keep the “highlight” in place

Comment: I used this in vanilla js to address a similar problem:

element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {e.preventDefault()}, {capture: true})

Comment: Hi @JorgeSolis thanks for the reply, any chance you might have a React implementation? I tried modifying your snippet but I cannot get it to work.